# One Outlook mailbox will not sync

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

## Overview

I have a user with 3x Office 365 mailboxes. I've found that 2/3 inboxes are syncing fine, the last one will not sync. We'll call the last inbox `last-inbox@example.com`.

## UX

Mailbox `last-inbox@example.com` is showing up in Outlook. It just has no emails in the Inbox or Sent Items. Nothing we do allows the inbox to sync down. The user **can** however get access to the inbox from https://outlook.office.com.

## Troubleshooting done so far

Below is the troubleshooting we've done so far:

1. Confirmed that the user can access `last-inbox@example.com` via OWA.
2. Deleted and recreated the user's Outlook profile.
3. Tried adding `last-inbox@example.com` under Account Settings > Add Mailbox.

## Question(s)

1. What would cause a shared EXO mailbox not to sync?
2. Has anyone else experienced anything like this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you create a new Outlook profile and only configure this last mailbox, did you get the same issue? And how did you configure the account, auto-configure by Autodiscover？When did this issue begin to occur? You also could test on another computer.

Comment: Hi @Jayce. a) I haven't tried just configuring the last mailbox because at the time I did not have the credentials for the shared mailbox. I will look into that as that's a good idea. b) Mailbox was configured via Autodiscovery. c) The issue appears to have happened within the last several weeks. Was working fine before that.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If the issue has been resolved, please mark the helpful replies as answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared mailbox didn’t have credentials.
After your admin has added you as a member of a shared mailbox, close and then restart Outlook. The shared mailbox should automatically display in your Folder pane in Outlook. You could try to configure the owner mailbox without the 3rd mailbox.

If the issue persists, you could try disabling caching for shared folders:

1. Open the mail profile settings in Outlook.
2. Click on More Settings.
3. On the Advanced tab, uncheck Download shared folders.